# Treat \n as a newline character for multiline formulas

Tags: google-sheets

Given some sheet at cell `A1` if I write `="foo\nbar"` then `foo\nbar` will be rendered as shown:

[image]

If I manually add a newline using the shortcut `cmd + opt + enter` then the expected output as shown:

[image]

It's a problem because it makes my formulas look bad, especially if I'm adding a title row with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637197/2909897).

- Is it possible to get some type of newline character interpolated?
- How do you format your multiline formulas?

Answer (score 23):

You can use `char(10)` instead of `\n`  so if you need to replace them you can do

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\n",char(10))
```

[image]

or if your building the formula from scratch you can do:

```
="foo"&char(10)&"bar"
```

[image]

Comment: How would you approach multi line cells? Is it bad practice for title rows?

Comment: multi line within a cell or multiple cells with newline? both are doable - as far as I'm concerned nothing is bad practice lol Ive built entire applications using only google sheets :-P if u have an example I can share how I would do it